# Remove Transitivity relation using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, break

I am using the following code to remove transitivity child->parent relation using hashmap. (The hashmap dataset is in terms of child->parent entry.)

```
private static void factor_transitivity(Map<String,String> dataset, boolean complete) {
    if (!complete) {
        complete = true; // Assume that on this check everything will come out to be OK.
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dataset.entrySet()) {
            if (dataset.containsKey(pair.getValue())) {
                complete = false;
                String value = dataset.get(pair.getValue());
                dataset.put(pair.getKey(),value);
                //System.out.print("");
                break;
            }
        }
        factor_transitivity(dataset, complete);
    }
}
```

Please notice the commented

```
//System.out.println("")
```

line. If I uncomment that line, then the code works fine. However, if I leave it commented, then I get an error message as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:362)
at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(HashMap.java:462)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:417)
```

Why do I get this strange behavior?

Comment: Show us more of the stack.

Comment: Provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , **including** a map that is filled with data that shows where the error actually happens.

Comment: yes, will upload a map with the data causing the problem as soon as I can identify the piece of the data myself. I have a very large input dataset, so will need some time to see for myself.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
http://ideone.com/zHX7NI

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
   // your code goes here
   factor_transitivity(new HashMap<String,String>(){{
     put("abc","abc");
     put("ghi","ghi");
     }},false );
   }
   private static void factor_transitivity(Map<String,String> dataset, boolean complete) {
   if (!complete) {
     complete = true; // Assume that on this check everything will come out to be OK.
     for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dataset.entrySet()) {
        if (dataset.containsKey(pair.getValue())) {
            complete = false;
            String value = dataset.get(pair.getValue());
            dataset.put(pair.getKey(),value);
            System.out.print("hello");
             break;
           }
       }
   factor_transitivity(dataset, complete);
  }
 }
}
```

Now you can see this code being recursive it keeps calling the factor_transitivity method and printing "hello" again and again. Even when I comment out the line the same error occurs(http://ideone.com/ffA0pG) due to the recursive nature of the method.

Comment: I was pointing that the code doesn't have anything to do with uncommenting/commenting the line. The error lies in the map.

Comment: You're not demonstrating anything when the line in question won't even be executed.

Comment: Edited but again I couldn't find any connection with the commenting/uncommenting of the print line